# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds when initializing List<int[,]>

Tags: c#, list

I have the following C# code:

```
List<int[,]> l1 = new List<int[,]>();
l1[0] = new int[1, 1];
```

It throws System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException right in face.

How come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are created empty by default, replace `[]` with `Add()`

```
 List<int[,]> l1 = new List<int[,]>();
 l1.Add(new int[1, 1]);
```

or use .NET 4.0 initializers (semantically the same as above):

```
  List<int[,]> l1 = new List<int[,]>(){new int[1, 1]};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  [List.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) on list and not index access  as `l1.Add(new int[1, 1]);`